# Why is write() not working correctly when I am using absolute paths instead of relative ones?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, zip, python-3.6

There is a file `Creep lyrics.rtf` on my desktop.I wanted to convert this into a zip file using Python. I used two approaches to this, one worked and one did not.

**Approach 1 ( which did work ):**

```
import zipfile,os

os.chdir('/Users/apple/desktop')

Toy=zipfile.ZipFile('lyrics.zip','w') #Toy is the variable name
Toy.write('Creep lyrics.rtf',compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) #This specifies to use the deflate compression algorithm.

Toy.close()
```

**Aproach 2 ( which did not work):**

```
import zipfile


Toy=zipfile.ZipFile('lyrics.zip','w')
Toy.write('/users/apple/desktop/Creep lyrics.rtf',compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
Toy.close()
```

As you can see, I have used the absolute path of the file `Creep lyrics.rtf` in the second case and I used a relative path in the first case.

As in most of the cases that I've dealt till now, it doesn't really matter if you use the relative or the absolute path! So should I always use a relative path while trying to create zip files or am I doing some mistake?

Comment: Only difference I can see is capital U for users in approach 1 but not 2. You may also need to escape the space in the file path, or rename it something without spaces.

Comment: @con-- In windows and osx it doesn't matter if you use U or u. However in linux, it does matter

Comment: They would't have to do any escaping of spaces.  The only difference I see is the uppercase vs. lowercase.  Also OP should explain why it isn't working and not just say "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Iguananaut as i said above,  it doesn't matter if you use U or u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an absolute/relative path problem. `os.chdir('/Users/apple/desktop')` changed your current working directory.

In the second one try to use

```
Toy=zipfile.ZipFile('/Users/apple/desktop/lyrics.zip','w')
```

Maybe you cannot create file in the current working directory. Are also, in OSx the path is case insensitive if the partition is formatted to be case insensitive (it is usually the case, but not always).

Lets make some examples:

#### Case sensitiveness

Your system has a single partition and that single partition is formatted to be case insensitive: than the paths `/Users/apple/desktop`, `/users/apple/desktop` and `/users/APPLE/DESKtop` (and so on...) are considered by the file system to be completely equal.

Now suppose that you give your software to a friend, that has a system with a single partition and that single partition is formatted to be case **sensitive**: than the paths `/Users/apple/desktop`, `/users/apple/desktop` and `/users/APPLE/DESKtop` (and so on...) are considered by the file system to be completely **different**. The path `/Users/apple/desktop` and `/users/apple/desktop` are inconsistent across different computers.

**Bonus point**: avoid to use spaces in paths. The shell understands a path with spaces as multiple paths, unless it is surrounded by quotes, that is annoying.

#### Current working Directory

You used `os.chdir('/Users/apple/desktop')` that is the same to issue `cd /Users/apple/desktop` in your terminal (to know what `cd` is, run `man cd` in your terminal).

That line changed the current working directory, or the directory in with respect to all relative paths are processed. You can know your current working directory with the command `pwd` in your terminal.

Let's make an example. You are running your python script in the root directory `/` for which your user does not have permission to write a file.
`Toy=zipfile.ZipFile('lyrics.zip','w')` tries to write a new file `/lyrics.zip` but you are not allowed by the system to actually write/create the file. So you have some solutions to adopt:

1. Changing your current working directory with `os.chdir`
2. Write in an absolute or a relative path in which you can actually write

etc. etc.

Comment: The U is not the only thing changed, leaving apart it is **extremely** bad programming behavior to use inconsistent paths.

Comment: Actually I am a beginner, so could you please tell me what are inconsistent paths? And thanks a lot for informing me :)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that it isnt working due to case sensitivity and the fact that you're not changing dir to the location of the zip file.

Changing `'/users/apple/desktop/Creep lyrics.rtf'` to `'/Users/apple/desktop/lyrics.zip/Creep lyrics.rtf'` might fix the problem